# how do I improve my simple mod_rewrite in htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using mod_rewrite for clean urls but I'm just having a small problem.

The line in particular is:

```
RewriteRule ^events/(.*)$ fe_events.php?event_url=$1
```

This works. I can go to url.com/events/something_or_other and it works as expected. The problem however is then if I just go to url.com/events it doesn't work - I've got to go to url.com/events/ (with a trailing forward slash on the end).

Can I simply modify this line or do I need to add another line such as:

```
RewriteRule ^events$ fe_events.php
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^events(/(.*))?$ e_events.php?event_url=$1
```

this should work.

Comment: It sort of works... url.com/events works as expected, but not if i try url.com/events/something it isn't sending that event_url properly

Comment: yes, because it always rewrites it to e_events.php?event_url=$1, it just cant check if $1 is empty. you can check if variable is not empty in your code or just use your own solution, which is quite good. i beleive you're checking if isset($_GET['event_url']), so checking if its not empty shouldnt be a problem.